# How to run commands as root on AWS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a AWS instances but I can't login as root, just can login with my account. What are the command I can use to edit root's files?

Comment: Use the "sudo" command to run as root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as said above it is best to use sudo or

```
$ sudo su root
```

but, if you really like to login as root, open

```
$ /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and set PermitRootLogin to true

then you can login to the instance as root.
(also restart ssh daemon, `# systemctl reload sshd`)

Comment: Thanks, that helps my use case. We were doing su - testaccount but if you try that as su - root it asks for the password ... and we login via pem files, so who knows what the password is? (yes, we could reset it). sudo su root works great, no PW prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run a command as root, you must prefix the command with `sudo`. Like,

```
sudo <command>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use sudo with the user you got, like ec2-user, ubuntu, centos etc.

```
sudo command_you_would_like_to_run
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
$ sudo su root
```

I had this problem for hours today...

To everyone suggesting to just "run commands with `'sudo' + 'command'`", that wasn't useful, the reason I was looking for this answer was because those commands wouldn't work, they all returned as PERMISSION DENIED or "Error: This command has to be run with superuser privileges (under the root user on most systems)."

Thankfully the top answer actually suggested to use SUDO to go to root, that actually helped because for some reason THAT command was accepted.

Maybe that's just obvious for many here, but I'm not used to using Linux, so follow that hint, from there on it starts working.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35478060)